# CircularQueue program is getting errors

Tags: java

I'm new to java. When I compile my code on the terminal it is telling me I am getting several errors and I am not sure why. Most of the errors are "can't find symbol"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircularQueue {

    private int head, tail;
    private String [ ] q = new String [ 10 ];
    private String name;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    public CircularQueue () {
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
    }

    public void insertQueue () {
        if (isQueueFull () )
            System.out.println ("Overflow");
        else {
            name = getName ();
            if (isQueueEmpty () )
                head = +1;
            if (tail==Size-1)
                tail=-1;
            q [++ tail] = name;
        }
    }
    public void deleteQueue() {
        String x;
        if ( isQueueEmpty () )
            System.out.println("Underflow");
        else {
            x=q[head];
            System.out.println ("Servicing " + x);
            if (head==tail) {
                head=-1;
                tail=-1;
            }
            else {
                head ++;
                if (head==Size)
                    head=0;
            }
        }
    }
    private String getName () {
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        return input.nextLine ();
    }
    public boolean isQueueEmpty () {
        return (head==-1);
    }
    public boolean isQueueFull () {
        return ((tail-head+1==0) || (tail-head+1==Size));
    }
    public void printQueueLogical () {
        int next;
        if (isQueueEmpty())
            System.out.println ("Empty");
        else {
            next=head;
            System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
            while (next != tail) {
                next ++;
                if (next==Size)
                    next=0;
                System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void printQueuePhysical () {
        for (int J=0; J<Size; J++)
            System.out.println (" q [" + J + "]= " + q [J]);
    }
    class TestCircularQueue {
        public static void main ( strings [] args) {
            CircularQueue n = new CircularQueue ();
            for (int J=0; J<3; J++)
            m.insertQueue ();
            m.deleteQueue ();
            m.printQueueLogical ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Size` defined?

Comment: Posting the error messages here will surely help!

Comment: Size isn't defined, how would I define it?

Comment: I don't know, how would you define it? It's your program. What is it supposed to be the size of?

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler says it can't find a symbol, this means that you probably have a syntax error. A symbol can be a keyword, some method name, an operator, etc.

Possible causes, for example (extracted from http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm)

1. trying to use a variable without declaring it.
2. misspelling a class or method name (remember, Java is case sensitive).
3. the parameters used do not match a method's signature.
4. the packaged class has not being referenced correctly using an import declaration.

What you can do?

You can read the stacktrace. The "can't find a symbol" exception usually comes with useful information, such as the offending symbol and the location in the code. For example (again, from the link above)

```
System.out.prontln("The perils of mistyping..");
```

will generate something like

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method prontln(jav.lang.String)
location: class java.io.printStream
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added some lines of code.Dint test your logic though and do not create unnecessary inner classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CircularQueue {

private int head, tail;
private String [ ] q = new String [ 10 ];
private String name;
int Size;
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

public CircularQueue () {
    head = -1;
    tail = -1;
}

public void insertQueue () {
    if (isQueueFull () )
        System.out.println ("Overflow");
    else {
        name = getName ();
        if (isQueueEmpty () )
            head = +1;
        if (tail==Size-1)
            tail=-1;
        q [++ tail] = name;
    }
}
public void deleteQueue() {
    String x;
    if ( isQueueEmpty () )
        System.out.println("Underflow");
    else {
        x=q[head];
        System.out.println ("Servicing " + x);
        if (head==tail) {
            head=-1;
            tail=-1;
        }
        else {
            head ++;
            if (head==Size)
                head=0;
        }
    }
}
public void setSize(int i)
{
    Size=i;
}
private String getName () {
    System.out.println("Enter name");
    return input.nextLine ();
}
public boolean isQueueEmpty () {
    return (head==-1);
}
public boolean isQueueFull () {
    return ((tail-head+1==0) || (tail-head+1==Size));
}
public void printQueueLogical () {
    int next;
    if (isQueueEmpty())
        System.out.println ("Empty");
    else {
        next=head;
        System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
        while (next != tail) {
            next ++;
            if (next==Size)
                next=0;
            System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
        }
    }
}
public void printQueuePhysical () {
    for (int J=0; J<Size; J++)
        System.out.println (" q [" + J + "]= " + q [J]);
}

}
class TestCircularQueue {
    public static void main ( String [] args) {
        CircularQueue n = new CircularQueue ();
        n.setSize(10);
        for (int J=0; J<3; J++)
        {n.insertQueue ();
        n.deleteQueue ();
        n.printQueueLogical ();}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i Think "size" means the length of the Array.... 
ie. `int size = q.length;`

and for some reason when creating the object of the class you used 'n' and then when you wanted to use it you used 'm' check that also

so after going through it...i think dis worked for me..although what you are trynna achieve...but you should sort the rest yourself

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class CircularQueue {

        private int head, tail;
        private String [ ] q = new String [ 10 ];
        private String name;
        int Size = q.length;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        public CircularQueue () {
            head = -1;
            tail = -1;
        }

        public void insertQueue () {
            if (isQueueFull () )
                System.out.println ("Overflow");
            else {
                name = getName ();
                if (isQueueEmpty () )
                    head = +1;
                if (tail==Size-1)
                    tail=-1;
                q [++ tail] = name;
            }
        }
        public void deleteQueue() {
            String x;
            if ( isQueueEmpty () )
                System.out.println("Underflow");
            else {
                x=q[head];
                System.out.println ("Servicing " + x);
                if (head==tail) {
                    head=-1;
                    tail=-1;
                }
                else {
                    head ++;
                    if (head==Size)
                        head=0;
                }
            }
        }
        private String getName () {
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            return input.nextLine ();
        }
        public boolean isQueueEmpty () {
            return (head==-1);
        }
        public boolean isQueueFull () {
            return ((tail-head+1==0) || (tail-head+1==Size));
        }
        public void printQueueLogical () {
            int next;
            if (isQueueEmpty())
                System.out.println ("Empty");
            else {
                next=head;
                System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
                while (next != tail) {
                    next ++;
                    if (next==Size)
                        next=0;
                    System.out.println (" q [" + next + "] = " +q[next]);
                }
            }
        }
        public void printQueuePhysical () {
            for (int J=0; J<Size; J++)
                System.out.println (" q [" + J + "]= " + q [J]);
        }
    }

public class TestCircular {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CircularQueue n = new CircularQueue ();
            n.insertQueue ();
            n.deleteQueue ();
            n.printQueueLogical ();
    }

}
```